# How to group values from a column in SQL using a value from another column?

Tags: sql, asp.net-mvc-5, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-mvc, dbset

I have a Table of languages, there's various columns but the 2 important ones are the `Origin` and `Destiny`.
when you select the Origin it search every `Destiny` that have the same `Origin`. Like:

`Portuguese|English
 Portuguese|German
 German|Italian
 German|Portuguese
 English|Portuguese
 English|German`

When I select `English` it only show `Portuguese` and `German`, when `German` shows only `Portuguese` and `Italian`, etc.

I am using `Dbset` on `asp.net core` and i am having trouble in the search logic.
This is the search logic that i am using, `IdiomaDestino` being `Destiny` and `idiomaorigem` being `Origin`

```
public async Task<List<string>> BuscarDestino(string idiomaorigem)
    {
        var x = await contexto.Idiomas.GroupBy(x => x.IdiomaDestino)
            .Where(g => g.Count() >= 1)
            .Where(w => w.Key == idiomaorigem)
            .Select(x => x.Key)
            .ToListAsync();

        return x;
    }
```

Comment: You've said what it does, but I didn't see where you say what you *want* it to do?

Comment: It is in the question, i want to know how to search the Database using a selected value and get all values in a column that have the same value matching from another column, i put it visually with the languages, but i can figure out the code logic. the one i use is not working